# Why does a calculated property return a property object when called from the class object, but an instance of the class returns the expected object?

Tags: python, class, properties, instance

```
class a_class():
    _x = []

    @property
    def x(self):
        return a_class._x

ac1 = a_class()

print(a_class.x)

print(ac1.x)
```

Why does the first print return a property object, while the second print returns the list object?

Comment: What do you mean by "class level calculated property"? `x` is just an ordinary property, no? This is the expected behavior for any properties. Could you clarify what different behavior you are expecting?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a "classmethod property"?

Comment: @Brian61354270, I meant 'class-level' in the sense that it was in juxtaposition to 'instance-level', meaning when I called the calculated property using the class's name, it would return the property object, but when I called it via the instance, it would work as intended. 

I just wanted to know why that was; turns out its because the ?dunder? method used to get an attr relies upon the instance, from what I gathered from Mous's answer.

I could have worded it better, in hindsight.

Edit: Edited the title of the question.

Comment: After your edit, I think you're looking for [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor). Both properties and methods are implemented as descriptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the property on the class won't call it; it's only called on instances. If it were to be called on classes, it would break method lookup, because method lookup reads attributes from the class of an instance, not from the instance itself.

```
class cls:
    @property
    def attr(self):
        print('Property was called')

cls.attr # doesn't output anything, and evaluates to the property
cls().attr # calls the property, outputting the string
```

When an attribute is looked up on an object (class instance) `obj`, Python will do the following:

1. Call `type(obj).__getattribute__(obj,attr)`/`type(obj).__getattr__(obj,attr)` where `attr` is the string name of the attribute (assuming the attribute exists, we only need to worry about the latter).
2. If the attribute is a descriptor (an object whose type defines a `__get__` method), then those methods will call the `type(descriptor).__get__(descriptor)`, and return that value as the attribute's value.
3. Otherwise, return the attribute value.

Objects of type `property` define the `__get__` method, and are therefore descriptors. For properties specifically, they will call their wrapped function. Therefore, when they are looked up on an instance, that `__get__` method will call the wrapped function. Equally, it won't get called when it's looked up on the class.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay thanks! So the class's dunder method that is called whenever I look up that property relies upon an instance? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @JoshuaMerrifield I've added another couple of paragraphs with an overview of the attribute lookup process in Python. If this helped you, you can upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense. Thanks for expanding the explanation!

Comment: @JoshuaMerrifield If this helped you, upvote and accept the answer. This will also help future users who have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't. I don't have enough reputation.

Edit: New to this. I realized I could accept the answer, but I still cannot upvote it b/c I don't have enough rep.